# Footnotetext update and use Footnote counter

Tags: footnotes

I want my `\footnotetext{test}` to use the current counter of `\footnote{test}` and update it.

Currently if I try:

```
\footnote{first}`
\footnotetext{second}
```

I see:

[image: 1]

But I want to see:

```
1 First
2 Second
```

It feels like `\footnote` and `\footnotetext` have 2 different counters.

Comment: To get `1 First 2 Second`, I'd expect to use `\footnote` twice, so what does 'use current counter ... [but] update it' mean? Your example certainly seems to use the 'current counter'.... (And of course there is `\footnotemark[<num.>]`, too.)

Comment: @jon I use `\footnotetext` because I don't want to have a link. But I want my `\footnotetext` and `\footnote` to essentially share the 'counter'.

Comment: Well, I agree: links to footnotes are pretty weird. But do you mean you don't want to have anything appear in the main text, but there's a 'footnote number' at the base of the page nonetheless?

Comment: @jon Yes. That is the only downfall. I have seen books that do that. I tried googling for "blank" footnotes but all of the implementations had problems. They either created invisible links or they created empty spaces, unlike `\footnotetext` which works flawlessly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should *compile* and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Another idea would be to use two different sets of footnotes; or, alternatively, there are many ways to put bits of text at arbitrary places on the page. But I am not clear on the purpose this 'blank' footnote serves, so it is hard to suggest a useful answer.  What does the numbered footnote, which has no corresponding point in the main text refer do? And what is its function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
some text\footnote{first}

\stepcounter{footnote}
some text \footnotetext{second}

some text\footnote{third}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to make this into a macro with name `myfootnote` ?